# Running same Pexpect program simultaneously on the same server but differnt terminals

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a **python pexpect code** lets say **Program1.py** which logs-in to one router from each program using pexpect.spawn and does required operations using sendline and expect modules in pexpect.

If I try to run this same program, from multiple prompts on my server with each program login to two diffrerent routers only one program seems to get the `expect()` input while the other instance of the programs times out at`child.expect()` -> at read `non_blocing()`

## Example:

### In prompt-1 on my RHEL Server I execute the program to login to router X with ARGs

```
bash$ python program1.py 10.11.12.13/2001 configure_MGMT
```

### In Prompt-2 on my RHEL Server I execute the program to login to router Y with ARGs

```
bash$ python program1.py 20.20.12.13/2020 configure_MGMT
```

one of the Programs runs successfully, while the other hits TIMEOUT at the first `child.expect()` call.

Is this due to the GIL?

Is there a workaround for this?
(I wish to avoid multiprocessing here, because my webserver handles the multiprocessing aspect and executes the same program multiple times.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this. Since python programs will always get executed synchronously and not in parallel, the pexpect will timeout waiting for input while the process is waiting to get scheduled.

to run all of them as background processes and in parallel, we need to use the '&' at the end of execution CLI.

Example:

bash$ python program1.py 20.20.12.13/2020 configure_MGMT &

thanks

Comment: repeating the same test case with just the '&' appended to the CLI fixed the issue for me. i tested for 5 executions in parallel, to 5 different routers.

Answer (score 1):

The GIL has nothing to do with this, because independent processes do not share a GIL.  The most likely cause of this is that your router only supports one log-in at a time.  The easiest way to verify that this is the problem is to remove Python from the equation by manually logging in to the router from two different terminal sessions at the same time.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the confusion. The login done is for two different routers. let me edit the post with that detail.

Comment: How do you distingish which router you are logging in to if you simpy type `python program1.py` ?  Have you tried printing out stuff to insure that you are, in fact, accessing different routers?  Does it matter which one you do first, or does one router always work and one not work?

Comment: the program accepts args, which is given by users via webserver. For simplicity i have mentioned only program1.py. Its not specific to one router, i tried with 7 different combination. i need concurrency, else this tool wont serve purpose. The traceback is always at exactly that expect( ), i have a function defined which i call wherenever there needs to be a sendline and expect couple.. that function hosts expect() call.. nowhere else in code i have used expect() explicitly.

Comment: Yes, i can see from my router side when and who logs in. Also i have logfile_read output data to see different logins and the point where it hangs. lets say one of the programs gets to expect first, the others which are spawned TIMEOUT.

Comment: I tried setting timeout to large numbers, like 15s. The active program is not actually stuck to that one expect and not releasing. it continues through its code and does lots of other stuff.

Comment: You keep saying webserver, but your example is from the bash prompt. Does that mean that the program you execute at the bash prompt is funnelled through a webserver?

Comment: Right on Patrick. HTML Form gives inputs to my PHP which runs the python.. Design apart, to debug this i am running the script manually with CLI Args, via multiple bash windows on my RHEL server with root permissions.

Comment: Your simplification was way oversimplified.  You didn't show separate arguments in different windows.  In any case, the GIL is not your problem, but there is obviously some resource limitation.  You should think about artificial constraints you have put on your program.  For example, perhaps you are trying to pass a the optional source_address parameter to socket.create_connection, and so only the first program to allocate this socket can run.